# How come TopoSort only works on certain graphs, and fails on others?

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I recently learned about the topological sort algorithm and how to implement it using dfs and stacks, so I coded up a solution to the problem [Reactivity Series](https://open.kattis.com/problems/reactivity) and implemented toposort directly. But I'm not sure why it gets Wrong Answer on test case #4. The test cases aren't public, so I don't even know the test case that's bad.

Anyways, I spent nearly 1/2 an hour trying to correct my solution, creating test cases etc., but couldn't make much head way. Any help on debugging will be appreciated. The code follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<vi> vvi;

vvi graph;
vector<bool> flag;
stack<int> topo;

#define sz(C) int((C).size())

void dfs(int i)
{
    if(!flag[i])
    {
        flag[i] = true;
        for(vi::iterator it = graph[i].begin();it != graph[i].end();it++)
        {
            if(flag[*it])
            {
                printf("back to the lab\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                dfs(*it);
            }
        }
        topo.push(i);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, k, a, b;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);
    graph.clear(); graph.resize(n); flag.resize(n, false);
    for(int i = 0;i < k;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
        graph[a].push_back(b);
    }

    dfs(0);

    while(!topo.empty())
    {
        printf("%d ", topo.top());
        topo.pop();
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Nib

Comment: Don't make marcos such as `sz`. They can cause problems.

Comment: @NeilKirk OK, advice noted, but usually it makes my life much much simpler to use a macro that to retype int(A.size()) every time I use it...

Comment: Either make sz a function, or figure out why you need to cast to int all the time and ask a better way.

Comment: I need to cast it to an int because the A.size() returns an unsigned integer, which I might compare, use with signed integers, hence creating bugs hard to find. Creating a function is a good idea, but that slows down(though vaguely) the code, as macros would only increase compile time, while functions may increase running time unnecessarily.

Comment: Simple functions can be inlined and in any case the overhead of functions is very small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will always print 0 first. Please note that it is not hard to think of a case where there is no valid topological sort with `0` as first element.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess your'e right. So, should I create a parent array and store parents of all nodes in it, and then hit dfs on node that doesn't have any parents ? What if there are multiple such nodes ? then, should I separately create pdfs trees of all of 'em and then, probably proceed to merge the two, or three, or more ? If yes, how can I do that, that appears to be an impossible task using stacks. Is there a way to do that without creating levels in which we store the "level"(depth) of a node in dfs tree ?

Comment: Actually when I write topo sort I don't use DFS - I do precisely what you propose in the comment. I have a container where I store all nodes with no parents. Then each time I print an element I "remove" it as parent from all of its child nodes and if necessary I add the child in the container. Algorithm is linear and not hard to implement

Comment: Hmmm, that's good actually. let me re-implement my solution and get back to you. :)

Comment: Have a look at the first algorithm [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms)

Comment: But I don't think your algorithm will be linear, it should be O(n^2), as if you run up against someone with no parent, you're gonna have to reiterate through the container to delete those with parent = current node. Or, is there some way to escape that time ?

Comment: Hmm my statement is a bit misleading. Topological sort is linear in terms of number of edges in the graph which may go up to `O(n^2)`. Still no better algorithm can possibly exist as you need to traverse all edges to make sure your sort is valid.

Comment: The wiki link sounds good, but as suggested by the other answer, no back edges would possibly exist in the graph. So, how should I avoid that problem ?

Comment: @Nib there is a special case handling for that in wiki - `if graph has edges then
    return error (graph has at least one cycle)`

Answer (score 0):

Your DFS only examines one connected component in the graph: the one containing metal 0.  You can't assume that there is a path from this metal to every other one.

Also, you seem to be reporting "back to the lab" when you detect *a vertex you have seen before* (which may or may not be part of a cycle -- but in any case, you're already told in the problem description that a cycle can't occur in the input).  You aren't testing for the right condition.

Comment: Your 1st point: Note my comment on the other answer.

Your 2nd point: you're right. I never paid as much attention to the line hat says that. In that case, "back to the lab" only happens when stack size after dfs doesn't equal the number of nodes, right ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Note [your] comment on the other answer": it doesn't contradict my first point in any way that I can see.  As to your last sentence: yes, if the graph consists of a single component then `topo` will contain 1 copy of every vertex; but still you need to change your DFS to *ignore* already-seen vertices, instead of causing it to report "back to the lab".